# Implicitum esse & obsessum teneri

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin

How would I translate the bolded sections of these lines?

. . . sine pudore & reverentia **intrepido animo** peccare, seu facere ea quae mala sunt; propriissime tamen significat **peccandi habitui implicitum esse & obsessum teneri**. Id enim videtur ista ambulatio velle, **quae motio quaedam** & agitatio est a spiritu mundi profecta.

. . . to sin without shame and regard for an untroubled mind, or to do those things which are evil; yet it most properly signifies to have been involved and obsessed to be bound to a habit of sinning. For walking seems to mean, a certain motion and agitation which has been effected from the spirit of the world,